# why is this init.d-script not being executed at system reboot?

Tags: linux, boot

I have a selfmade init.d script on a Linux box that worked fine with Debian 4 and Debian 5 but with Debian 6 (fresh install) it gets only executed at system boot but not before rebooting.

The script is pratically this one:

```
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          selfheal
# Required-Start:
# Required-Stop:
# X-Start-Before:    mountall
# X-Stop-After:      umountfs
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: selfheal tool
# Description:       Saves/restores the user partition at (re)boot
### END INIT INFO

echo $0 $*
sleep 3

# some useful stuff follows here...
```

At `reboot` I see the system switching to `runlevel 6` and unmounting the file systems (see that `X-Stop-After: umountfs` above). No sign of life from my `selfheal` script.

At system *boot* however, I see the `echo` line and the script is being executed.

I've installed the script using:

```
rm /etc/rc*.d/[SK]??selfheal && update-rc.d selfheal defaults
```

no errors/warnings there. The symlink exists:

```
root@intermodul:~# ls -al /etc/rc6.d/
total 12
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 May 16 16:09 .
drwxr-xr-x 68 root root 4096 May 16 16:07 ..
<snip>
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   18 May 16 15:09 K09umountfs -> ../init.d/umountfs
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   18 May 16 16:09 K10selfheal -> ../init.d/selfheal
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   20 May 16 15:09 K10umountroot -> ../init.d/umountroot
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   16 May 16 15:09 K11reboot -> ../init.d/reboot
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  351 Jan  1 06:34 README
```

Note that with Debian 6 came concurrent booting and I guess there is something wrong with my "INIT INFO".

What is wrong here?

### Update

The script gets executed when setting `CONCURRENCY=none` in `/etc/init.d/rc` but I'd like to have makefile concurrency enabled. So, why doesn't the script get executed in makefile concurrency mode?

Answer (score 1):

I found the reason:

The script needed the following line in the `BEGIN INIT INFO` section so that the root fs is not being unmounted before my script finishes:

```
Should-Stop:       umountroot
```

This causes `umountroot` to become "dependent" on my script.